# htaccess: Redirect to www without knowing the domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I know you can redirect the client from a domain without www to the domain with www. But I found only solutions with entering the domain-name, like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is, I want to redirect the user from domain example.com to domain www.example.com without knowing that it´s "example.com". So it could also be helloworld.com but should also redirect to www.helloworld.com.

So is there a way to work with variables here? For example redirect %DOMAIN% if %DOMAIN% doesn´t contain www. at the beginning to www.%DOMAIN% (with directories)?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: +1 from me! Works like a charm. Is there a way to implement it with https if the page was requested with https?

Comment: For sure. I added it in my answer. Don't forget to accept it if this worked for you